# How to access shared folder on Windows 10 from Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10

I have a share on Windows 10 Pro that is accessed by Windows 7 and 10 with no issues. On Windows XP machine, I can ping both the hostname and the IP, however I get error 64 when I tried net use and cant access it from File Explorer.

Any ideas how to access file share from XP hosted on Windows 10?

Comment: Is that even possible? Windows XP is far, far out of support now, and you should have gotten rid of it years ago. Don't be surprised if _literally everyone_ gives you the same advice.

Comment: @michael Well, we have what we have, and stating the obvious isn't really helpful :-) This is an old computer in a warehouse that they will probably replace now with Win7 one, tho the issue is now. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to enable SMB1 protocol on Windows 10 like it's described here:

https://winaero.com/blog/enable-smb1-sharig-protocol-windows-10/

Hope it will help!

Comment: Wow. SMB1... The thing we wanted to oust for years, and when it is finally done, you have to enable it back again. Thanks. Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

SMB1 is notorious for many severe vulnerabilities, so you can consider setting up an private FTP server using IIS or other software for achieving this.

Comment: You are correct, but what should I do with a fleet of printers that support only SMB1?

Comment: @mrmut Do what they did in Office Space. Or just get rid of them. No sense keeping things that "work" if they are no longer fit for purpose.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Get rid of a fleet of excellent printers because of SMB1? That is quite wasteful and I would not get approval for that. Even on newer devices Canon does not support SMB3, so I would gain nothing.

Comment: @mrmut SMB2 is still a thing. Anyway, you take a risk by keeping the printers. As long as management is informed and willing to live with that risk, that's all you really need to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unfortunately, SMB2 is also not supported on any Canon printer. What I could do is separate fileserver for printer (scanning) and minimize attach surface. However, given that I designed, implemented and maintain the entire network, I doubt system could be compromised.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Maybe a local FTP is a solution. Not sure tho. Some NTFS folder redirecting would be at play.